# find ORF with minimal size of 45 bases using perl regular expression - why this regex doesn't work

Tags: regex, perl

I am using perl and regular expression to find an ORF (open reading frame) with a minimal size of 45 bases using.
Basically it means: 
Find a substring a string that is composed ONLY of the letters ATGC (no spaces or new lines) that:

1. Starts with "ATG"
2. ends with "TAG" or "TAA" or "TGA",
3. is at least 39 chars long
4. is dividable by 3

My first code was:

```
$CDSString = "ATGCACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACATGA";
if($CDSString =~ m/(ATG.{45,}(TAG|TAA|TGA))/) 
{
    my $CDSCurrent = $1;
    if ((length($CDSCurrent) % 3) == 0)
    { 
        # do something
    }
}
```

which works fine, but I thought there might be a better way.
So I tried:

```
$CDSString = "ATGCACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACATGA";
if ($CDSString =~ m/ATG(...){13,}(TAG|TAA|TGA)/ )
{
    # do something
}
```

but for some reason it doesn't match the string above it, and I can't figure out why.
Can anyone figure it out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: it seems to be working for me now. weird. could have sworn it didn't work before. thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not making sure that everything between the start and stop codons is in fact composed of the letters `ATGC` only. You should be using:

```
if ($CDSString =~ m/ATG(?:[ATGC]{3}){13,}(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)/i) {...}
```

(But your original regex works, too, it just won't reject invalid matches. So there may be another problem somewhere else.)

Comment: thanks for the improvment, i did not think about handling non-ATGC chars! i have no idea why it works for me now and not before.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the code thus far.  What you should be looking for is the FIRST instance of a stop codon.  If your CDS is no good, it might contain internal stops.  Internal stop codons make an invalid ORF, so you need something more finessed:

```
if($CDSString =~ m/ATG(?:[ATGC]{3}(?<!TAG|TAA|TGA)){13,}(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)/i) {...}
```

This will return a sequence without internal stops that has at least 13 codons between the start and the first stop.

This portion of the code: `(?:[ATGC]{3}(?<!TAG|TAA|TGA))` says "match three nucleotides that are not TAG, TAA, or TGA".  The (?

Here's how it looks in action:

```
perl -e '$CDSString = "ATGCACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACATAGTAGTAGTGA";if ($CDSString =~ m/(ATG(?:[ATGC]{3}(?<\!TAG|TAA|TGA)){13,}(TAG|TAA|TGA))/ ){print "$1\n"}'
ATGCACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACATAG
```

Note, the last 3 stop codons (TAGTAGTGA) are not returned as part of the sequence.