# perl regex: howto get open-reading-frames without internal stop-codons?

Tags: regex, perl, substring, bioinformatics

I'm trying to isolate all overlapping ORFs from one strand of a (DNA) genome sequence in string format (including start (i) and stop (j) positions on the genome and length (l) of the ORF); the ORFs should start with ATG, have at least 24 internal nucleotides [ACGT] and end with (TAA|TAG|TGA).

By looking at [find ORF with minimal size of 45 bases using perl regular expression - why this regex doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153000/find-orf-with-minimal-size-of-45-bases-using-perl-regular-expression-why-this) I came up with this (so tweaking was required):

```
    my $genome = $_[0];
    my $ATG_count = 0;
    my $ORF_count = 0;
    my @i = (); 
    my @j = (); 
    my @l = (); 
    my @frames = (); 

    while ($genome =~ m/ATG/ig) {   ### I need to do this to find every ORF starting with ATG, including ORFs which are located inside other ORFs.
        $ATG_count++;
        my $start = $-[0]+1;
        foreach (substr($genome,$-[0]) =~ m/^ATG(?:[ATGC]{3}){8,}(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)/ig) {
            my $length = $+[0];
            if ($length%3 == 0) {   ### I need to do this because sadly, the above regex DOESN'T recover only Strings are dividable by 3. (Why not?!?)
                my $stop = $start+$length;
                my $readingframe = ($start%3);
                push(@i, $start), push(@j, $stop), push(@l, $length), push (@frames, $readingframe);
                $ORF_count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, the above code recovers ORFs that begin with ATG, end with (TAA|TAG|TGA) and are >=30 alright - I have tried it - BUT the recovered ORFs have internal stop codons!

My question is how I can make the recovered ORFs stop at the first stop-codon after ATG? I guess one possibility would be to exclude (TAA|TAG|TGA) from the middle part of my regex -> `(?:[ATGC]{3}){8,}`
but how would I do that?

Many thanks in advance!

#### Edits:

Ok, after trying the suggestions below, I came up with a solution which recovers all overlapping ORFs with >=30 bp from a given genome sequence, which start with ATG and have no internal stop-codons:

```
    my $genome = $_[0];
    my $ATG_count = 0;
    my $ORF_count = 0;
    my @i = (); 
    my @j = (); 
    my @l = (); 
    my @frames = (); 

    while ($genome =~ m/ATG/ig) {
        $ATG_count++;
        my $start = $-[0]+1;
        foreach (substr($genome,$-[0]) =~ m/^ATG(?:[ATGC]{3})*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)/ig) {    
        ### This was changed so that it matches "ATG - first(lazy) stop-codon". 
            my $length = $+[0];
            if ($length%3 == 0 && $length >=30) {    
            ### This was changed so that the matches must be >=30 in length.
                my $stop = $start+$length;
                my $readingframe = ($start%3);
                push(@i, $start), push(@j, $stop), push(@l, $length), push (@frames, $readingframe);
                $ORF_count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern as you have written it will greedily search for codons until it reaches the final stop codon in the string.  Try rewriting your pattern like this:

```
m/ATG(?:[ATGC]{3}){8,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)/ig
```

Adding `?` to `(?:[ATGC]{3}){8,}?` tells the regex engine to match as many codons as possible up until the first stop codon, instead of the last.  I would also omit the `^` from your patter, with the assumption that the start codon is not going to be the first codon in your sequence.

As for ensuring that the returned string contains no stop codon, wrap the result in a second regex test that checks for a stop codon.  As far as I can see, there is no way to do a variable-length negative look-behind test for this in a single regex pattern.

Comment: Ok thanks, this works much better than before, but I still recover ORFs with stop codons in the first 8 units :P
How would you improve it so that a stop-codon in ( (?:[ATGC]{3}){8,} ) recovers a non-match?

Comment: the ^ATG is there because in the for-loop I try matching the substring that starts at the ATG recovered in the while loop, so that each ATG in the genome is tested for the presence of a ORF.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible using a single regex pattern, since it involves a variable length negative lookbehind.  You might have to wrap the result of the first regex test within a second test to see if the returned string contains a stop codon.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the 'repeating' unit ( `(?:[ATGC]{3}){8,}` ) non-lazy by adding a `?` after it:

```
^ATG(?:[ATGC]{3}){8,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)
                     ^
```

See an example [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/xV1vO6) on two genomes the first with a stop codon before the last stop codon.

Basically, it will make the least possible matches of the 'repeating' units and stop at the first stop codon seen that is not within the initial 8 units.

Now, if you want to stop at the stop codon within those 8 units, don't use `{8,}` since it means 'at least 8'. Use `+` instead, which means "at least 1" or `*` meaning at least 0.

```
^ATG(?:[ATGC]{3})+?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)
                 ^
```

**EDIT:** After discussion in comments, it turns out there are also strings like `ATGTAA` which means there are no triplets in between the start and end codons. This said, using `*` as mentioned just above will be the correct regex:

```
^ATG(?:[ATGC]{3})*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, this works much better than before, but I still recover ORFs with stop codons in the first 8 units :P
How would you improve it so that a stop-codon in ( (?:[ATGC]{3}){8,} ) recovers a non-match?

Also, wow, thanks for the regex test site, this goes straight to the bookmarks.

Comment: @user2560852 Oh, you want those that go within the first 8 triplets? Then change it to `^ATG(?:[ATGC]{3})+?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)`. I'll update my answer in a few. Also, you're welcome! :)

Comment: No, this doesn't work much better... I now think that I should rewrite ( (?:[ATGC]{3}){8,} ) so that it does not look for 24 [ACGT] matches, but for 8 (TAA|TAG|TGA) mismatches, or any matches except these...

Comment: Hi, I tried some varieties and just exchanging *? for +? and leaving {8,} out worked, because with +? I still got some hits where the first codon after ATG was a stop-codon. Now I only get hits with ATG first and TAA TAG TGA only at the very last position. after that, I simply weed out the ORFs <30 in the if condition. Thanks for your help! //// another question: why am I shown as user2560852 and not as my account name?

Comment: @user2560852 Oh! So you were also getting genomes of ATG TAA (or similar with other stop codons)? If so, then yes, you would use `*` instead of `+`. For the last question, I don't quite remember, but I think your username and account name are separate. You can change your username on your profile with 'Edit' :)

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153000/find-orf-with-minimal-size-of-45-bases-using-perl-regular-expression-why-this/32486720#32486720). What you need is a negative assertion look-behind.  It does not have to be variable width.  From the other post:

```
m/ATG(?:[ATGC]{3}(?<!TAG|TAA|TGA)){8,}(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)/ig
```